# Mongoimport upsert problem

Tags: mongodb

I have file with this JSON

```
{
_id :     10000000042,
OtherID: 10000000043,
}
```

> C:\mongodb-win32-i386-1.9.0\bin>mongoimport.exe --host localhost --db
>   crm --collection tst --file c:\temp\tst3.txt --jsonArray --upsert
>   --upsertFields OtherID
>
> connected to: localhost imported 1 objects

In mongo console:

```
    > db.tst.find();
    { "_id" : NumberLong("10000000042"), "OtherID" : NumberLong("10000000043") }

> db.tst.getIndexes()
[
        {
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "crm.tst",
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "v" : 0
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("4e435d7a296ca66d8f50b0e0"),
                "ns" : "crm.tst",
                "key" : {
                        "OtherID" : 1
                },
                "name" : "OtherID_1",
                "v" : 0
        }
]
```

Then i updates my JSON:

```
{
_id :     10000000042,
OtherID: 10000000044,
}
```

and run mongoimport again

In console:

> ```
>     > db.tst.find();
>     { "_id" : NumberLong("10000000042"), "OtherID" :NumberLong("10000000043") }
> ```

OtherID field does not updated.

My hands are broken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the "upsertFields" parameter and you're golden. That isn't needed for what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Remon, thanks. I'm tried this earlier but it doesn't work. But not all's ok, it works!